# implementing PBKDF for encrypting a string in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, string

I am looking forward to implement encryption using `PBKDF2`..
Could you please provide sample code if possible. on implementing `PBKDF` for encrypting a string..
Thanks..

Comment: To make sure that you're clear, `PBKDF2` is a key-derivation function (a hash). It is not an encryption algorithm. You cannot reverse it. `PBKDF2` is generally used as a step *towards* encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is an example, not production code.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
+ (NSData *)doKeyForPassword:(NSString *)password
                        salt:(NSData *)salt
                     keySize:(NSUInteger)keySize
                      rounds:(NSUInteger)rounds {
    NSMutableData *derivedKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:keySize];

    NSData *passwordData = [password dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, // algorithm
        passwordData,               // password
         passwordData,              // passwordLength
         salt.bytes,                // salt
         salt.length,               // saltLen
         kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,         // PRF
         rounds,                    // rounds
         derivedKey.mutableBytes,   // derivedKey
         derivedKey.length);        // derivedKeyLen

    return derivedKey;
}
```

Very simple test, use a better salt
and a better rounds count, possible using CCCalibratePBKDF.

```
- (void)test_doKeyForPassword {
    NSData *key = [Crypto doKeyForPassword:@"password"
                                      salt:[@"salt" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                   keySize:kCCKeySizeAES128
                                    rounds:1000];
    NSLog(@"doKeyForPassword: %@",key);
}
```

If you are copying this code to use in a production app: Don't. This is just example code. Basically if one needs this code they should not be doing cryptography. Hire a domain expert, at a minimum have the code vetted by a domain expert.

Comment: You can't use `password.length` here. That will compute the number of characters, not number of bytes. For multi-byte characters, you'll truncate it. Either use `-lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`, or convert first to `NSData` first (I recommend the latter). I had exactly this bug in RNCryptor until just recently. Very embarrassing. https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/77

Comment: @Rob True, it was just a one-off test of CCKeyDerivationPBKDF, not designed to be used for production. Thanks! Changed.

Comment: @RobNapier after implementing PKDF I am having a hard time in how to use it with the AES Encryption/Decryption. I even posted a question but I got no help. I am stuck after implementing PKDF please see through this link and please kindly answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679465/how-to-add-salt-to-aes-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypting-it-using-objective-c